# SSRS - Using Date format that is not built in

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services, formatting, business-intelligence

I am working on a report in SQL Business Intelligence 2008 that has a table where one cell must contain a Date value (not DateTime, so just month, day, and year). Right now the expression for that cell would be as follows:

```
=Fields!MyDateValue.Value
```

The problem I have is that this date must be displayed in the format dd-MMM-yyyy, eg January 1, 2000 would be 01-JAN-2000. I was looking through the formats available in Properties->Number, and this format does not seem to be built in. Is there a way to get the cell to display the date in this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
=Format(Fields!MyDateValue.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

For upper case month, as you indicated:

```
=UCase(Format(First(Fields!order_entry_date.Value, "ReportMain"), "dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should separate data from presentation. This is important if exporting your report to Excel - if you format the `Value` as a string then the field will be exported to Excel as text, not a date, making sorting and formulas difficult.

Leave the `Value` as just the field: `=Fields!MyDateValue.Value` and for the `Format` property of your cell put in your date format: `dd-MMM-yyyy`. This is the preferred method so that your columns retain their data type on export.

However, this will display the month with a leading capital, not all in uppercase like your example shows. If you need the month to be uppercase then you have to format the cell `Value` to a string manually:

```
=UCase(Format(Fields!MyDateValue.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=Day(First(Fields!inserteddate.Value, "DataSet1")) &" - " &left(MonthName(Month(First(Fields!inserteddate.Value, "DataSet1"))),3) &"-" &Year(First(Fields!inserteddate.Value, "DataSet1"))
```